# React Hooks: Passing state prop is NOT a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state-management

I am passing state hooks as props to my components and my 'setCity' works perfectly fine but when I try implementing setFlag I get an error saying "Searchbar.jsx:15 Uncaught TypeError: setFlag is not a function"

So why can I set the value of city but not flag?
I pass the props from 'App' to 'footer' which passes to 'searchbar'.

```
function App(){
  const [city, setCity] = useState("");
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Header className='header' />
      <Body className='body' city={city} flag={flag}/>
      <Footer className='footer' setCity={setCity} setFlag={setFlag}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Footer({setCity}, {setFlag}){
    return(
        <div className='footer'>
            Footer
            <Searchbar className='searchbar' setCity={setCity} setFlag={setFlag}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
function Searchbar({setCity}, {setFlag}){

    handleChange = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.target.value);
        setCity(e.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("submitted");
        setFlag(false);
    }
    return(
        <div className='searchbar'>
            <form>
                <select defaultValue="default" onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="default" disabled>Choose a state...</option>
                    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                    ...
                </select>
                <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>Search</button>
            </form >
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Typo? `{setCity}, {setFlag}` -> `{setCity, setFlag}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the props are passed as the first argument of the component,

```
function Searchbar({setCity}, {setFlag}){
```

should be

```
function Searchbar({setCity, setFlag}){
```

Same apply for `Footer`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. where a function (here setCity, setFlag) was not recognized as a function in the child of a child.  My solution that didn't use typescript or the propTypes library was to wrap setCity and setFlag in new functions in the first child and then pass those new functions to the next child.

Answer (score -1):

**Are you still facing ?**

```js
Uncaught TypeError: setCity is not a function
```

```js
const { setCity=()=>{}, setFlag=()=>{} } = props
```